# Hyperref and the float package

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing

There is an issue when using the `hyperref` package, which provides links and bookmarks, together with the `float` package, which implements changes in float placement in the document.

Loading both has the side effect of making all links generated by hyperref lead to the first page of the document, instead of the appropriate page. The following MWE reproduces the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[pdftex,
            bookmarks=true,
            breaklinks,
            pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{float}      
   \restylefloat{figure}
   \restylefloat{table} 


\begin{document}

\lipsum[20-27]

\begin{figure}
\centering
A figure.
\caption{Figure caption}
\label{label}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-8]

Link to figure: \ref{label}.
\lipsum[17]

\end{document}
```

In this example, the `label` reference leads to the first page, and not to the page where the figure actually is.

I haven't found any mentions to this in either the `hyperref` or the `float` documentations.

Comment: Loading the `float` package before `hyperref`, as suggested in the answer, also seems to eliminate "`pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier ... has been already used, duplicate ignored`" type errors.

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this issue is to load the `float` package *before* `hyperref`, issuing commands that affect floats *after* loading `hyperref`:

```
(...)
\usepackage{float}      

\usepackage[pdftex,
            bookmarks=true,
            breaklinks,
            pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\restylefloat{figure}
\restylefloat{table} 

(...)
```

I'm not sure about why this behavior occurs, but I can assume that there is some command redefinition in `float` that breaks links generated by `hyperref`.

Comment: This is wrong, too. To get correct results in all aspects, the order should be: Load `float`, load `hyperref`, use `\newfloat` resp. `\restylefloat`. See also `hyperref` README and http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=hyperdupdest